# Ember js big table

Tags: ember.js

I have a page with a few tables, in total there are a few after 1000 rows.

After the tables is ready, when I click to go on another page, the route is changing in the address bar, but nothing happens until a few seconds. 
Then the new page is rendered.

Why is that and what can I do?

Comment: are you sure that is related with the big table? can it be related with the component that exist within the new route you navigate to?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the new page route you are shifting to has a model hook that takes a bit to load. If that is indeed where your slowdown is then you can add a loading substate to your application to display a loading spinner of some kind.

More details available here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. It seems is not the model. The truth is I don't use the model. I do an ember-ajax request from controller. The problem is that I click on something - nothing happens for 1 - 3 seconds and then the loading appears and the request is made. Someone told me that could be the table tear down. But I do not get a solution for that.